# Как сжать видео под размер экрана.

Tags: java, android, видео, glsurfaceview

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Красным это видео. Черным это размер экрана телефона. Я использую SurfaceView.

Как мне подогнать видео под размер экрана. орентировываясь по ширине Экрана телефона.
Сохраняю пропорции.

В ImageView все просто. Добавил картинку и она сама с сохранением пропорций отображается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать именно `SurfaceView`, то стоит сделать так:

1. Например у нас есть такая разметка:

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
             android:orientation="vertical" 
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <SurfaceView
       android:id="@+id/surfaceViewFrame"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="center" >
   </SurfaceView>
   ```
2. Подключаем необходимые нам элементы:

   ```
   surfaceViewFrame = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceViewFrame);
   player = new MediaPlayer();
   player.setDisplay(holder);
   ```
3. А теперь немного расчетов добавим в ваш `MediaPlayer` в `onPreparedListener` и пересчитаем высоту и ширину видео фрагмента в соответствии с текущими  размерами экрана, избежав растягивания.

   ```
   player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onPrepared (MediaPlayer mp){
       int videoWidth = player.getVideoWidth();
       int videoHeight = player.getVideoHeight();
       float videoProportion = (float) videoWidth / (float) videoHeight;
       int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
       int screenHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
       float screenProportion = (float) screenWidth / (float) screenHeight;
       android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = surfaceViewFrame.getLayoutParams();

       if (videoProportion > screenProportion) {
           lp.width = screenWidth;
           lp.height = (int) ((float) screenWidth / videoProportion);
       } else {
           lp.width = (int) (videoProportion * (float) screenHeight);
           lp.height = screenHeight;
       }
       surfaceViewFrame.setLayoutParams(lp);

       if (!player.isPlaying()) {
           player.start();
       }
      }
   });
   ```

Comment: А какие рассчеты надо сделать если нужно по высоте рассчитать?

Comment: @EraNewGames если сделать расчет по высоте, то вы не вместите всю картинку, как в вашем схематичном примере

Comment: А что разве нет у SurfaceView параметра. Который бы просто сохранял пропорции. А я бы просто указывал размер ширины или высоты. Неужели проще нельзя в Андроид....

Comment: @EraNewGames проще только с использованием VideoView

Comment: @EraNewGames хоят чего конкретновы хотите добиться гибкости или простоты, ну и вас присутствуют ограничения в виде использования `SurfaceView`

Answer (score 1):

Для видео лучше брать специальную вюху. Посмотрите сюда [VideoView](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/videoview.php)

Comment: Кастомный видео плеер у меня. Не пдоходит videoView